# Multidimensinal Matrix with each index 2 values

Tags: matlab

Can any one send me code of generating a 3*3 matrix with each index have 2 values using rand integer commands.

Comment: Um you mean `ones(3) * 2`?

Comment: means (3,2) on every index two values

Comment: you can make me any size matrix i will adjust but the main reason every index has two values which i cant can be able to generate

Comment: I have no idea what you want. Please show an example in your question

Comment: draw an matrix like [(3,2) (4,5);(4.5) (6,7)]

Comment: You need to use a cell array: `{[3 2], [4 5]; [4 5], [6 7]}` or a 3D array that is 3 x 3 x 2

Comment: well it was just a matrix i want to generate just this type of matrix using rand function can you send me code .if you design. actually i am new to matlab

Comment: `rand(3,3,2)` will create a 3d matrix.